# Json dentro de otro, llega vacío petición POST

Tags: java, python, json

Tengo un programa que consulta un servicio REST en python, y el servidor Java que procesa las peticiones.

Python

```
import requests
import json

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

headers={'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
#Parametros peticion
parametros={
    "llamada":"S", 
    "backup":{
        "fecha":"2019-11-14T00:00:00",
        "codigo":"1W78-55155W8S"
        },
    "usuario":"MK001"
    }


r = requests.post(
    'http://localhost:8080/appapi/calculo/eje1',
    data=json.dumps(parametros),
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'),
    headers=headers
)
```

En la parte Java:

```
@POST
@Path("/eje1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response setCalc(HashMap<String,String> object) {
    System.out.println(object);
    return Response.status(200).entity("").build();
}
```

Cuando ejecutamos el JSON

```
parametros={
"llamada":"S", 
"backup":{
    "fecha":"2019-11-14T00:00:00",
    "codigo":"1W78-55155W8S"
    },
"usuario":"MK001"
}
```

Los parámetros que vienen con valor son solo `llamada` y `usuario`, pero `backup` me viene vacío.

¿Conocéis la forma de montar ese Json en particular? La parte Java no puedo modificarla.

Comment: ¿ Has probado a ejecutar con postman el servicio Java para asegurarte que está devolviendo bien los datos y no es problema del python ?

Comment: Si, la parte Java la he probado con Soap UI y además también la consumo con otros programas.

Comment: En vez de recogerlo en Python como un objeto, ¿ podrías recogerlo como una cadena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En java los terminos Map -> JSON son muy confusos. No te recomiendo hacer eso. Deberias transformarlo en un objecto utilizando el mappeo o en un String, dado que quieres trabajar de forma abierta y sin que el modelo te influya te recomiendo la libreria de org.json

https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json

```
@POST
@Path("/eje1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response setCalc(String json) {
    System.out.println(json);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    //Con este objecto ya podrias trabajar
    System.out.println(json.toString());

    return Response.status(200).entity("").build();
}
```

**EDICIÓN:**

Para la parte python pon un cadena de String, en vez del objecto, pero luego en el back de java deberás que tener que reparsearlo.

```
import requests
import json

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

headers={'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
#Parametros peticion
parametros={
    "llamada":"S", 
    "backup":"{\"fecha\":\"2019-11-14T00:00:00\",\"codigo":\"1W78-55155W8S\"}",
    "usuario":"MK001"
    }


r = requests.post(
    'http://localhost:8080/appapi/calculo/eje1',
    data=json.dumps(parametros),
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'),
    headers=headers
)
```

Comment: Hola Raúl, la parte java no puedo modificarla, ya se está usando desde otras aplicaciones.

Comment: Probaste a poner solo un nivel de json? {
"llamada":"S", 
"backup": "2019-11-14T00:00:00",
"usuario":"MK001"
}

Comment: Así sí que funciona, el problema es cuando backup contiene un json dentro que no llega nada.

Comment: Con esto te va a llegar, pero vas a tener que luego reparsearlo en la parte java: {
  "llamada": "S",
  "backup": "{\"fecha\": \"2019-11-14T00:00:00\",\"codigo\": \"1W78-55155W8S\"}",
  "usuario": "MK001"
}

Comment: Funciona Raúl, si quieres escribe esto en la respuesta y la acepto, gracias por todo.

Answer (score 1):

Si no puedes modificar la parte Java, modifica los datos para que coincidan con algo *digerible* por ese controlador.*Aplana* el JSON, por ejemplo (sólo se admite un nivel de profundidad):

```
parametros={
    "llamada":"S", 
    "backup-fecha":"2019-11-14T00:00:00",
    "backup-codigo":"1W78-55155W8S",
    "usuario":"MK001"
}
```